# How to fix "imap_utf8" doesn't work for the email's body in php imap

Tags: php, utf-8, imap

I created a php code to get all the new emails from gmail using imap - also in Hebrew. When I try to use the "imap_utf8" function, it's working only for the subject - and not for the body. (I also noticed that the subject has a different encoding than the body)

I searched a lot in the web, and I didn't find any solution. (I also new to php)

```
foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 1);

        echo imap_utf8($overview[0]->subject);
        echo imap_utf8($message);
}
```

I expect the output of Hebrew for the subject and the body, but only the subject works.

for example - if the subject is "נושא", and the body is "גוף", so the result is: 
"נושא" for the subject (And this is great), 
15LXldejDQo= for the body

(And the encoded code for the subject is =?UTF-8?B?16DXldep15A=?=)

Thank's!

P.S: I'm sorry if my English is not very good.

Comment: Is the message a `A MIME encoded string`? Subject line in email is definitely a *special* case. See: [`iconv_mime_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode.php)

Comment: A: Thank you very much for the quick answer. B: iconv_mime_decode worked only for the subject, but not for the body.

Comment: Guess I am confused... `15LXldejDQo=` looks to me like `גוף`, just base64 encoded. If you are looking for a good read... https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045

Comment: How do I convert it to utf8 using php?

Comment: Nothing to convert. I think simply [base64_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) it.  *Decodes data encoded with MIME base64*

Comment: Working great!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two functions differ slightly.

- base64_decode — Decodes data encoded with MIME **base64**
- imap_utf8 — Converts MIME-encoded text to UTF-8

If you only ever read one RFC the [Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) one is a good one to consider.

```
<?php
$body = '15LXldejDQo=';

var_dump(base64_decode($body)); //output: גוף
var_dump(imap_utf8($body));     //output: 15LXldejDQo=

$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?16DXldep15A=?=';
var_dump(base64_decode($subject));  //output: Q1|^�^W^�^@
var_dump(imap_utf8($subject));      //output: נושא
```

Basically header encoding uses a different technique. You san see this in the subject line... `=?charset?encoding?encoded-text?=`. The `B` is for base64, a `Q` would be fore quote-printable. The message is simply base64 encoded, the content type established by the `Content-Type` header.